# How to make a safari webpage portrait mode while keeping the iPad landscape mode?

Tags: ipad

The title is a little weird and complex, so here is an example.

[image: Something like this]

That was photoshopped, but is there a way to make that actually possible in an iPad? Trying to make the webpage portrait mode, and the iPad is still in landscape mode? Anything helps!

Comment: This smells like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: And @DavidPostill I like to use landscape mode because of an it’s an iPad, but I want to go on this webpage that only allows portrait mode. It’s very annoying flipping my iPad to portrait.